# C "if" structure

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am learning C and my question might be silly but im confused.In a function like:

```
  int afunction(somevariables)
    {
        if (someconditions)
        {
         do some stuff
         return 1;
        }
        raise_error("error happened")
        return 0;
    }
```

My question is,if the if statement isnt meeted(success),then it will go to the raise_error ? in other words,does the raise_errors position act like if it was in a else statement,or its because you have to return something at the end(return 0)?or would it need a proper else statement?Basically im confused on how to make a propre if condition--if this condition isnt meet--then call raise_error.

thank you!

Comment: You return before `raise_error` is called (if `someconditions` is true).  The control flow leaves the function.

Comment: Because of the return, it breaks out of the method before reaching the error if the if is met. So that is the behavior you would notice. For clarity however, if you want that error based on the if, put it in an else.

Comment: in this case, if someconditions is verified, then the function returns 1 so the function exits and the rest of the code (raise_error) isn't executed

Comment: What makes you think the code **after** the `if` **statement** is in anyway affected by the statement before it?? And why the `return` is not executed? We are no tutoring site. What **specifically** in your C book and online resources you can very easily find about both statements do you not understand?

Comment: before it will reach the `return 0` `raise_error` will be executed first. But I think no need for the other person to answer this question just run the code and see it for yourself. :)

Comment: In general, you don't want to use too many `return` statements in your code.  It is not considered good coding practice. You should use `if-else` statement for your purpose. To answer your question, yes the above code snippet will in effect work the same way as `if-else`.

Comment: @Ozeta buf if it is not verified? what happen there? does it go to the raise_error?

Comment: @VHS: This is a disputable position. There are coding styles which use such structure like filters for parameters and value errors instead of a bunch of nested conditionals and possibly `bool` helper-flags or `goto` constructs.

Comment: @ChristopherM. yes of course. it executes raise_error("error happened"), then goes back to afunction(somevariables) and then returns 0

Answer (score 0):

> if the `if` statement isn't met (success), then it will go to the `raise_error`?

Yes. When `if` condition is not met, the control is passed to `else` branch if it exists; otherwise, the entire `if` statement is skipped.

> in other words, does the `raise_errors` position act like if it was in a else statement?

In this case, the answer is "yes", but only because your `if` branch is structured in a way that terminates the function due to `return` statement at the end.

Without that `return` at the end the control would go to `raise_error` upon completion of the `if` branch.

Answer (score 0):

> in other words,does the raise_errors position act like if it was in a else statement

Yes. Unless `raise_error()` does something that exits process, the `return 0` will be executed aferwards.

> Basically im confused on how to make a propre if condition--if this condition isnt meet--then call raise_error.

The code is fine. But if it makes it easier to understand then you can use an `else` clause too.
Your code is functionally equivalent to:

```
 int afunction(somevariables)
    {
    if (someconditions) {
         do some stuff
         return 1;
        }
    else {
        raise_error("error happened")
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code or line that is not under some condition will always be executed unless you get out of the code before getting to that unconditional line. You don't need else in this case since you return 1 and does not execute remaining lines